# Override a Magento 2 xml file

Tags: magento2

I am trying to override `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component/design_config_form.xml` to allow html tags in the copyright area. I thought all I needed to do was copy the file to `app/code/vendor/module-theme/view/adminhtml/ui_component` and edit it. Then it would be picked up in preference to the core file. However, this isn't working (and I've cleared all my caches). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should copy design_config_form.xml file to here.

```
app/code/YOUR_BRAND/YOUR_NAME/view/adminhtml/ui_component/
```

Comment: Please consider adding a short description about why it solves the problem.

Comment: But doesn't that require me to specify a module? I wanted to override without creating modules etc. If this is the only way, can you point me to where I set up YOUR_BRAND/YOUR_NAME so magento will go there? I'm familiar with Magento 1 but 2 is all new!